# Getting 'meta_value' when searching for matching 'post_id' and 'meta_key', 'meta_value' combo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, mysqli

[postmeta table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYbGj.png)

The end result is matching an array of *'post_id'*, sorted by the number of attendees. I know it is a WP backend but I have to do it in SQL, no *'get_posts'* or anything WordPress related. What I'm wanting to do is confusing so I'll try to be clear.

**What I Have To Begin:**

- **$check_post_ids** - the original array of post_ids I need to check
- **$start_date** - the *'meta_value'* each event's *'_StartDate'* needs to match.

**What I Need To Do:**

I need to check these three post_ids to see if they have a matching start date. If they do, I need to get an array of post_ids sorted from the highest to lowest number of attendees.

---

Currently I was planning on doing this with multiple SELECTs and foreach() statements, but I feel like there has to be a simpler way to do this ( i.e. One SELECT & foreach() ). Here's what I'm doing at the moment. I haven't finished it yet because I feel like there has to be a simpler way to do this. Newer to SQL and any help is tremendously appreciated!

```
    $check_post_ids = array('484', '627', '982', '2435');       
    $start_date = '1963-10-20 19:30:00';            

    // iterate through array of post_ids and check if they have the same _StartDate
    foreach($check_post_ids as $id){
        $start_date_check = "SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` =" . $id . " AND `meta_key` LIKE '_StartDate' AND `meta_value` = '" . $start_date . "'";
        $start_date_check_result = mysqli_query($conn, $start_date_check);

        // assign all post_ids with a matching _StartTime to a new array
        if (mysqli_num_rows($start_date_check_result) > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($start_date_check_result)) {
                $matching_post_ids[] = $row['post_id'];

                // iterate through matching_post_ids array, get the _NumAttendees for each, and assign their id and _NumAttendees to an assoc array to be sorted
                foreach($matching_post_ids as $id){
                    $attendees_check = "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = " . $id . " AND meta_key = '_ecp_custom_2'";
                    $attendees_check_result = mysqli_query($conn, $attendees_check);
                    if($upvotes_check > 0){
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($attendees_check_result)){
                            $sort_by_attendees['id'] = $id;
                            $sort_by_attendees['attendees'] = $row['meta_value'];
                            $sort_by_attendees_array[] = $sort_by_attendees;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Messing with it again and I can see that my code here is all sorts of out of whack, but hopefully it helps you get the basic idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of the query, I think you can simplify your code by using `SQL IN` keyword. Basically it substitutes the role of your first array with all your post IDs. Then, you can write a SQL query like this :

```
SELECT meta_value 
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = '_ecp_custom_2' 
AND post_id IN (SELECT post_id
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE post_id IN ('484', '627', '982', '2435')
AND meta_key LIKE '_StartDate' 
AND meta_value = '" . $start_date . "'")
ORDER BY meta_value DESC
```

There are 2 queries. The first one in the parenthesis, subselect all the post ids on your table wp_postmeta where post_ids have ids in your list and if they match with your starting date. Then, the main query selects all meta_values (I suppose attendees) based on your first subquery (all post ids with your starting date).

Hope it will help you.

Comment: You da bomb! Thank you! Just in case there's somebody else trying to copy and paste this, you do have to move the last double quote (") from after start date to after DESC. I also needed the post_ids to be dynamic because they were coming from an array so I used implode() on the array so I could use a variable. Thanks again for your help, I really appreciate it!